# How can detect that the flash movie projector is active window

Tags: flash, projector, active-window

How can detect that the flash movie projector is active window

Answer (score 0):

[`focusIn` and `focusOut`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3afocusIn)